# Printing all values of a struct with mixed values?

Tags: go

Is there any way of printing a struct with mixed value types, including pointer types, such that all value are shown? For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type test struct {
  Str string
  Ptr *string
}

func main() {
  s := "some string"
  p := &s

  t := test{
     Str: s,
     Ptr: p,
  }

  fmt.Printf("%#v\n", t)
}
```

I want something like: `main.test{Str:"some string", Ptr:(*string)("some string"}`
instead of: `main.test{Str:"some string", Ptr:(*string)(0x1040a120)}`

https://play.golang.org/p/YkZrPOeQ_Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no fmt verb you could use for that functionality. You could implement [Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) on your struct and have full control over how the struct is printed.